# Replace group for all matches

Tags: java, regex

I only want to replace words in a string, if there is no word character `(\w)` or hyphen **before or after** the word.

Text:

```
#button .button large-button tinybutton size9button #9button button-large buttontiny
```

Exptected result after replacement:

```
#text .text large-button tinybutton size9button #9button button-large buttontiny
```

Regular Expression:

```
(?<![\w-])(button)(?![\w-])
```

1. The regular expression currently only matches the first occurrence (button after `#`). What do I need to do to match all occurrences?
2. How can I replace `button` with `text` or any other word in Java?

I have read the topic [Can I replace groups in Java regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988655/can-i-replace-groups-in-java-regex), but I really do not understand how to use the example code for my special case. Unfortunately I haven't got any code to show. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead in `replaceAll` method:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<![\\w-])button(?![\\w-])", "text");
```

Alternatively you can use lookarounds and word-boundary:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<!-)\\bbutton\\b(?!-)", "text");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR1sC7/2)