# replacing string with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I think I have a decent handle wrt matching strings using Regex in Java, but now I am trying to replace strings using `Regex` and not having much success.

Simply put, I am trying to find where there is a digit immediately followed by a constant string "CMR", then adding a space between the digit and the "CMR" substring.  "`0CMR`" should become `"0 CMR", "5CMR"` should become "5 CMR", etc.  Any preceding non-digit should be left as it was.

So my source string is "`theStringThat0CMRhas`"

my command is:

```
replaceAll("[0-9]CMR", "[0-9] CMR");
```

I get the added space in the result, but the result becomes "`theStringThat[0-9] CMRhas`" which obviously isn't what I need.  Somehow I need to tell Regex not to replace with "[0-9]", but with whatever it matched on in the first place.

I know I'm doing this wrong, but I don't know what's right.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/988655/438992 and so on; searching the web for this turns up plenty of information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use a [*capturing group*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg):

```
replaceAll("([0-9])CMR", "$1 CMR")
```

`$1` references the first group in the match, denoted by parentheses.

Also, `[0-9]` can be substituted with `\d`.

Comment: Can you add some description and instructions explain how this works? As a Java beginner won't understand what are you typing about.

Comment: Perfect answer, @shmosel.  Not only showed the solution, but included the name and url of the description where I can go for more in-depth knowledge of the subject.  Thanks muchly!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"," ")
```

It uses look ahead for non digit character and negative look ahead for digit characters.

If you want just do it for the one with CMR after the digits, use:

```
"(?<=\\d)(?=CMR)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should group the number regex and call argument. Your code here:

```
replaceAll("([0-9])CMR", "$1 CMR");
```

For more regex knowledge, please read this document
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

a good starting point may be here for reading regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

on this site the replacing string page is here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacetutorial.html

$with a number represents a whole regex match, and you can use these to refer to what you were doing

```
    String testString = "theStringThat0CMRhas";
    String resultString = testString.replaceAll("[0-9]CMR","$0");
    System.out.println(resultString);
```

this would result in the answer: theStringThat0CMR has

you obviously didnt want this, so lets change the answer up a little

```
    String testString = "theStringThat0CMRhas";
    String resultString = testString.replaceAll("([0-9])CMR","$0 CMR");
    System.out.println(resultString);
```

now we are referencing the parenthsis, in which it hasn't done anything yet, so its replacing what it found, with the same thing, a space, and CMR

your result would now be: theStringThat0CMR CMRhas

so lets reference the part where we have chosen the number

```
    String testString = "theStringThat0CMRhas";
    String resultString = testString.replaceAll("([0-9])CMR","$1 CMR");
    System.out.println(resultString);
```

now your answer will be: theStringThat0 CMRhas

it is finding where it picked a number, replacing it with that number, a space, and then CMR

you are trying to do what I believe to be called a backreference though I am unsure. Regex is still not my strong suit either.