# Java replace link in a tag

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have

```
String s = "<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">https://stackoverflow.com</a><br/><a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>"
```

Now I just want to replace all links in the `href` attributes, by prefixing with a fixed value (e.g. `abc.com?'). Here's the result that I want:

```
String s = "<a href="abc.com?url=https://stackoverflow.com">https://stackoverflow.com</a><br/><a href="abc.com?url=https://google.com">https://google.com</a>"
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't resolve the problem because it replaces *all* strings beginning `http://`, not only those within `href` attributes:

```
s= s.replaceAll("http://.+?(com|net|org|vn)/{0,1}","abc.com" + "&url=" + "$0");
```

What can I do to replace only within the attribute, and not in other content?

Comment: Use an HTML parser. And in general, try to write a program that follows your definitions: look for the `href`, not for the `http`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HTML Parser such as [JSoup](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup)

```
String s = "<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">https://stackoverflow.com</a>";
Document document = JSoup.parse(s);
Elements anchors = document.getElementsByTag("a");
anchors.get(0).attr("href", "...new href...");
```

Alternatively if this is too heavy weight a regex should suffice:

```
<a href="(?<url>[^"]+)">(?<text>[^<]+)<\/a>
```

*Note if you dont care about the `text` group, replace `?<text>` with `?:`*

Just replace the `url` & `text` group using a similar approach to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988778/2279831)

Answer (score 0):

As said  by RealSkeptic look for href instead of the link itself, it saves a lot of effort.

```js
var s = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">https://stackoverflow.com</a><br/><a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>';

s = s.replace(/href="/g,"href=\"abc.com&url=" );

console.log(s);
```