# Split String at different lengths in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a string after a certain length.

Let's say we have a string of "message"

```
123456789
```

Split like this :

```
"12" "34" "567" "89"
```

I thought of splitting them into 2 first using

```
"(?<=\\G.{2})"
```

Regexp and then join the last two and again split into 3 but is there any way to do it on a single go using RegExp. Please help me out

Comment: I mean you want to split on length 2, 4 and 7 ??

Comment: i dont know about regex for different length but you can do it using substring  inside any loop.

Comment: is there a pattern of length like 2,2,3,2,2,3.... ??

Comment: You need to say what is so *regular* about pattern you want to find, or delimiter you want to match. Without it we can't really help you use regex for your problem.

Comment: @Pshemo It's like there are a lot of strings like the example above and I want to split them into 2,2,3,2 length and every string has exactly 9 numbers that's the pattern.

Comment: OK, so posted answers should do what you wanted. `split` is not the way here, use Matcher's `find()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the help I'll give it a try and let you all know if there are any concerns.

Comment: It works thank you, everyone, for helping me out... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `^(.{2})(.{2})(.{3})(.{2}).*` (See it in action in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/03DnMS/1)) to group the String to the specified length and grab the groups as separate Strings

```
  String input = "123456789";
  List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.{2})(.{2})(.{3})(.{2}).*");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

  if (matcher.matches()) {
     for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
         output.add(matcher.group(i));
     }
  }

  System.out.println(output);
```

**NOTE:** Group capturing starts from **1** as the group 0 matches the whole String

**And a Magnificent Sorcery from @YCF_L from comment**

```
  String pattern = "^(.{2})(.{2})(.{3})(.{2}).*";
  String[] vals = "123456789".replaceAll(pattern, "$1-$2-$3-$4").split("-");
```

Whats the magic here is you can replace the captured group by `replaceAll()` method. *Use **$n** (where n is a digit) to refer to captured subsequences*. See this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988655/can-i-replace-groups-in-java-regex) for better explanation.

**NOTE:** here its assumed that no input string contains `-` in it.
 if so, then find any other character that will not be in any of
 your input strings so that it can be used as a delimiter.

Comment: You are a wizard @YCF_L :D hats off to you !

Comment: yes. though I assumed that. But its better to mention. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

test this regex in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) with `123456789` test string.

```
^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{2})$
```

output :

```
Match 1
Full match  0-9 `123456789`
Group 1.    0-2 `12`
Group 2.    2-4 `34`
Group 3.    4-7 `567`
Group 4.    7-9 `89`
```