# How to use regex to replace each match in first column?

Tags: java, regex

I have multiple line string below

> A002334**001**93445 123394**001**
>
> A834858**001**93471 982**001**134

I would like to replace 001 in the first column to 002

> A002334**002**93445 123394**001**
>
> A834858**002**93471 982**001**134

I have try `^A[0-9]{6}(001)` with `string.replaceAll(matcher.group(1), "002")` but it replace all 001 to 002

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Comment: @K.Smith Probably not since based on example OP doesn't really want to replace *all* occurrences of specified string but only those in first column.

Comment: @K.Smith That question is a **JavaScript** question, not a **Java** question, so it cannot be the duplicate of this question.

Comment: The duplicate explains the basics, but also look at the documentation of [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Comment: Actually, the dupe is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988655/can-i-replace-groups-in-java-regex. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024941/3832970).

Answer (score 2):

Based on "I have multiple line string" I am assuming you have one string which contains data like:

```
String data = "A00233400193445 123394001\n" +
              "A83485800193471 982001134";
```

In such case your pattern `^A[0-9]{6}(001)` is quite close to final solution, but you will need

- to use [`MULTILINE` flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) which lets `^` and `$` to match not only start and end of entire text, but start and end of each *line*. That flag can be enabled by `(?m)` syntax which starts section for regex where flag should be applied.
- to store somewhere match of `A[0-9]{6}` part, which can be done by [capturing-group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), like you did for `(001)` part (probably unnecessarily here since you don't really want to *reuse* that match anywhere).

So your final solution can look like

```
String data =
        "A00233400193445 123394001\n" +
        "A83485800193471 982001134";

data = data.replaceAll("(?m)(A[0-9]{6})001","$1002"); //$1 represents match of group 1 (A[0-9]{6})

System.out.println(data);
```

Output:

```
A00233400293445 123394001
A83485800293471 982001134
```

Comment: Great answer mate. Crystal clear, as always : )

Answer (score 1):

You could use [string.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) passing the regex as a string and use multiline using an inline modifier `(?m)`

```
(?m)^(A[0-9]{6})001
     |         |
     | group 1 |
```

In the replacemen use group 1 followed by 002 `$1002`

```
final String regex = "(?m)^(A[0-9]{6})001";
final String string = "A00233400193445 123394001\n\n"
 + "A83485800193471 982001134";


System.out.println(string.replaceAll(regex, "$1002"));
```

Output

```
A00233400293445 123394001

A83485800293471 982001134
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/uf8ryk)